# Dompdf: Can i import pdf as background

Tags: dompdf

i have a pdf form that i need to be able to import as a background then use Dompdf to overlay html/text.

can this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dompdf is a library for converting HTML -> PDF. I'm no expert on that particular library but as far as I can tell it doesn't do things like overlaying html/text.

PDF cannot be imported into HTML because it isn't an HTML format and it isn't an image. There might be a parser library somewhere (e.g. http://www.pdfonline.com/easyconverter/sdk/pdf-to-html/), but without your own fairly extensive work you wont get that PDF document to be displayed in HTML.

HOWEVER, you CAN use something like this, it'll show your PDF document as the background, create a div that covers the screen just above the PDF document to make it non-interactive, then you can put all your contents above that. Note that there will be controls showing on the sides which as far as I know can't be prevented since they're provided by the browser when displaying a PDF file (you could use some fancy JS/CSS to prevent it I'm guessing but I don't know exactly how off the top of my head).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PDF as background</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;position:absolute;top:0;z-index:0;"></iframe>
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1"></div>
<div id="content" style="position: absolute;top:50%;left: calc(50% - 4cm);z-index:2">
<h1 style="font-size:20px;background:#00ff00;">I am on top of the PDF document!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think i may be able to merge PDF's together after I've generated the html to go over the letterhead PDF using fpdf. not tested yet but looks like you can merge pdfs.

Comment: Does not work here. Is there some configuration to apply?